# How can I write a function that subtracts two values only if the rows are visible?

Tags: vba, excel

I have two columns of data:

```
Member  Time
A        1
B        1
B        2
A        2
A        3
A        4
A        5
B        3
B        4
```

Say this data starts from `A1` to `B11`.

If I want to subtract consecutive time values after the column values have been sorted in ascending order all I need is this formula:

`=B3-B2`

The formula works fine to get me the difference. However, if I filter to get the difference only for member A, the formula considers the hidden rows as well, hence giving the wrong output.

I am new to VBA. Based on an answer provided in [another website](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/45637-have-formula-consider-only-visible-rows.html), I tried writing a function as follows:

```
Function MyDiff (MyRange As Range) As Integer

Dim c As Range
For Each c In MyRange
    If (c.Value = 1) And (c.EntireRow.Hidden = False) Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").value - Range("B1").value 
    End If
Next c

End Function
```

This function is not providing the anticipated output. Should I be using a different approach or is there something fundamentally wrong with my code?

Comment: Try your `if` with `or` instead of `and`

Comment: Meh. not with it, ignore me. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
MyDiff = MyDiff + IIF(c.Column = 1, 1, -1) * c.value
```

instead of

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").value - Range("B1").value
```

(not tested)

Comment: I tried that too. However, it doesn't provide the correct output. If the time column is `1
2
3
4
5
6
7
` 
The difference column is turning out to be `-1
0
0
0
0
0
0
`
I think the reason for this is the program having range, instead of selecting and finding the difference in two subsequent rows and then extending that to the entire column.

Comment: Ok, maybe I should have asked one or two more question: are you using MyDiff within any spread sheet as a function writing into column C the formula `=MyDiff(A1:B1)`? If so, then the function I wrote should work. If you are using the function differently then you have to explain some more.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you need to subtract the current row against last occurence of the non-filtered list, which is slightly tricky, however below just tested and works:

```
Sub MyDiffsub()
Dim FirstOcc As Boolean
Dim PreviousRng As Range

Dim c As Range

Set MyRange = Range("A2:A11")
For Each c In MyRange
    If c.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
        RowNumber = c.Row
        If FirstOcc = False Then
            FirstOcc = True
        Else
            c.Offset(0, 2).Value = c.Offset(0, 1).Value - PreviousRng.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
        Set PreviousRng = c
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

you would need to change the `MyRange` to whatever range is that you need, but it has to be the first column of the dataset. Also bear in mind that this is a `Sub` rather than a `Function` so it has to be ran after you filter the data set to the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Use this VBA code to define your function:

```
Function GetVisibleValue(ByVal rngData As Range) As Variant

    Dim i As Long

    If rngData.Areas.Count > 1 Then
        'Invalid range reference was provided, return #REF! error
        GetVisibleValue = xlErrRef
        Exit Function
    End If

    For i = rngData.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        If rngData.Cells(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            GetVisibleValue = rngData.Cells(i).Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

End Function
```

Then in the Excel sheet, in cell B2 and copied down use this formula:

```
=B2-N(GetVisibleValue(B$1:B1))
```

Here are images of the results before and after filtering:

[image: tigeravatar example (before)]

[image: tigeravatar example (after)]